# error 415 Unsupported Media Type for an angular spring boot application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, post, angular-httpclient

I develop a  angular 8 Spring boot 2 application

I try to send a POST request from an angular service, but I have the error 415 Unsupported Media Type

service angular

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const options = { headers: headers };
return this.http.post<Search>('/api/produitimmobilier/all', search, options).pipe(.......
```

I tried 2 configuration of my spring boot 2 controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/produitimmobilier/all",
method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes ="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Search findAll(@RequestBody Search search){
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/produitimmobilier/all",
method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
@ResponseBody
public Search findAll(@RequestBody Search search){
```

but I have the same error. Can you help me ?

Comment: Does it work as expected if you test it in Postman or Swagger ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, there was a bad mapping in Search object, a setter which was not correct. The discussion is closed. Thank you for reding this post